# Upload progress on nginx

Tags: 7, files

I am using the latest version of Drupal 7 and my webserver is Nginx. I checked the status report and it says:

> Upload progress Not enabled
>   Your server is not capable of displaying file upload progress. File upload progress requires an Apache server running PHP with mod_php.

How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 7):

Try with the [FileField Nginx Progress](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_nginx_progress) module.

> This module provides support for an upload progress bar for a backend/server implementing the RFC 1867 upload using multipart/form-data. Nginx does not yet support RFC 1867 uploads in
>   its suite of official modules. You can use the Upload 3rd party module to do that or just rely on PHP FastCGI support for RFC 1867.